# how to make this syntax possible in node.js console (javascript)

Tags: javascript, node.js

The same function `summ` :

`summ(7)(3)(5)`   must equal 15

and

`summ(7)(3)+5`   must equal 15

and

`summ(7)(3)`   must equal 10

How to make it possible?

Comment: `summ` should return something that can optionally be treated as either a function or a number...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `toString`/`valueOf` method to treat result as a value.

```
function sum(a) {
  chain.valueOf = function() {return a;}
  return chain;

  function chain(s) {
    a += s;
    return chain;
  };
}

sum(7)(3)(5)  == 15  // true
sum(7)(3) + 5 == 15  // true
+sum(7)(3)(5)        // 15
```

Comment: `valueOf` makes more sense for non-string values, though

Comment: I've edited my question. Help, please. Thank you!

Comment: @hearwhtti, what's wrong? it works. It must to return a function to possibility of next call, but `valueOf` allow us to interpret this function as a value. `+sum(7)(3) === 10`, `sum(7)(3) == 10`. What more you need?

Comment: I'm studying, can you, please, explain: why 'sum(7)(3) === 10' returns false and  '+sum(7)(3) == 10' returns true. What is purpose of '+'  ?

Comment: `+val` is like `0+val` just type conversion to numeric. `sum(5)` result has `function` type. It's why strict equality `===` fails. After type conversion with `+sum(5)` both side has `number` type and same value.